# What to do with the server tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Ok, the one that agree with the [server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) tag to stay can step up and answer this questions:

> Can you objectively determine whether the tag does or does not apply to a given question?
>
> Can you say that a question is “about ”?

This is taken from the [What is a meta tag?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/what-is-a-meta-tag) and should serve as guide to when you are dealing with a meta tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you objectively determine whether the tag does or does not apply to a given question?

Kinda. Any question asking for any kind of server or server-like behaviour should go with this tag.

> Can you say that a question is “about ”?

Yes and not. I know what a server is "to server some resource" but after that I have no idea what else I could tell about it.

---

I think that we should stress the rule:

> (...) tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, **are not allowed.**

A question using server as single tag is not good enough to tell me something about the question except a vague idea that OP is asking for some resource serving application. So, no, we should remove the server tag.

Comment: Your final rule would forbid tags like `desktop-client`, `windows`, `linux`, `open-source`, and others as well.

Comment: @Izzy you are escalating things. Those tags by itself tell me some category well defined: OP wants the recommendation to run in windows/linux and it should be open-source. I haven't seen the desktop-client tag but I don't believe is as dangerous as server tag.

Comment: I don't see what makes the `server` tag that different. But I'm waiting for other opinions (except for yours and mine ;) Might well be you're right, and I'm just a bit "gridlocked" here. But might as well be you're afraid of non-existent ghosts. This should be decided by more than two people. So thanks for raising it here on Meta, which is the place for exactly that :)

Comment: So, this is the answer PRO `server` or against it?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer against.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of it:

This answer is **PRO** [server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server)

Unfortunately my reasoning would be almost identical as Braiam's Anti answer; just my conclusion basically is the opposite - inline with Izzy's thoughts. So vote away everyone.